# How to prevent file modification in git reposiory

Tags: git

How can I prevend to be touched a particular file also if I checkout a branch where there is this file.
I tried with gitignore but it there is in the branch it will be overwrite.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make Git "forget" about a file that was tracked but is now in .gitignore?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1274057/how-to-make-git-forget-about-a-file-that-was-tracked-but-is-now-in-gitignore)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To prevent changes from being tracked after you ignore the file you'll need to tell Git to remove it from tracking:

```
git rm --cached <file>
```

If you're asking how to block changes to a file, Git doesn't do that.